# How to abort a client request

Tags: python, django, fork

I have this code in my application that use Django framework:

```
import os, time
def get(self, request, id=None):
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        self.run()
        time.sleep(600)
    else:
        time.sleep(20)
        return write_response()
```

I create a child process that will create the data that will be returned. I really need to do the work an child process. The function `run` use an external software to calculate the data to return. If I don't create a new process only the first request will succeed (the external software constraint).

The child process take about 10 seconds to do the work. The parent wait 20 seconds and then return a response using the data calculated by the child. For the client everything is working. In the server I get exception (`Broken pip`).

When the child continue executing the client has closed the socket so it raise an exception. What should I do to fix my problem?

Comment: I think it's better to use the Celery for these kind of tasks.

Comment: If the parent has to wait for the child, I suggest just using `subprocess.check_output()`